# Add require to a input field based on another field from the same form

Tags: forms, input, require

I have a form with 2 input fields and i want to add atribute require to the second input if the first field is completed and to remove the require attribute if this field is empty. This is the form:

```
<form id="someid">
 <input type="text" id="input1">
 <input type="text" id="input2">
</form>
```

Bellow is the code that i have tested

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#input1").on("keyup change", function() {
    var value = this.value;

    if ($("#input1:contains('" + value + "')").length > 1) {
        $('#input2').addAttr('required');​​
    }
    else {
        $('#input2').removeAttr('required');​​​​
    }
});  
</script>
```

Comment: `$('#input2').addAttr('required');​​` must be `$('#input2').attr('required', true);​​`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please test this:

**Update:**

```
$(document).on("keyup change", "#input1", function() {
    if (this.value.length > 1) {
        $('#input2').attr('required', true);
    }
    else {
        $('#input2').removeAttr('required');
    }
});
```

Comment: @A.Marian Ok, i'm going to fix it up.

Comment: @A.Marian It has to work now, test it again please.

Comment: It's ok. Thank you!